# Issue while running npm run sonar

Tags: sonarqube, jfr

I am using sonar for analysis of nodejs code but when I run npm run sonar I get this error

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Failure when starting JFR on_vm_start
```

when when I run the command with my root user it works fine.What could be the reason for same?

Comment: What version of the JDK are you running? If you are using JDK 9 or later, start with -Xlog:jfr*=trace for more information. On earlier Oracle releases, use -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=loglevel=trace